# How can you use autoconf to check if member of httpd.h typedef structure exists

Tags: apache, cross-platform, autoconf, apache2-module, pike

How do I make GNU autoconf script to test for typedef struct members using APXS as the compiler?

I have defined the following tests but the results are not what I'm expecting...

```
AC_CHECK_MEMBER(struct conn_rec.remote_ip, define 'USE_CON_REC_REMOTE_IP',,[#include "httpd.h"]);
AC_CHECK_MEMBER(struct conn_rec.client_ip, define 'USE_CON_REC_CLIENT_IP',,[#include "httpd.h"]);
AC_CHECK_MEMBER(struct conn_rec.remote_addr, define 'USE_CON_REC_REMOTE_ADDR',,[#include "httpd.h"]);
```

All of these tests are returning "no" even though I know that the first test and the last test should return "yes". I suspect this may be because these are typedefs instead of structs, and/or because autoconf isn't using APXS to run the tests.

The full code is at https://github.com/rritoch/PikeVM/blob/master/root/boot/system-1.1/apache/configure.ac

I am hoping there is a preexisting solution that doesn't require making custom test scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AC_CHECK_MEMBER` is for the C/C++ compiler. There are [apxs macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_with_apxs.html) to help setup compilation with apxs.  It shouldn't be too hard to translate `AC_CHECK_MEMBER` into a macro suitable for apxs.

Comment: Thanks, this solution wasn't easy to figure out though. tmp_ac_compile=$ac_compile
ac_compile='$APXS -c conftest.$ac_ext'
# AC_CHECK_MEMBER calls
ac_compile=$tmp_ac_compile